# Is there way to get private signed keystore file from previous apk release file?

Tags: android

I have created the private signed keystore file using eclipse and I have released the apk files in android market website. After some days we got some issues from users and we have fixed the issues but I don't have private signed keystore file.
While making the apk file I need to use private signed keystore file used in previous version release.

Is there way to get private signed keystore file from previous apk release file?

Comment: If you could generate the private key from the signed apk, the security wouldn't be worth much :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

You sign your APK using your *private* key, at which point your APK then contains your public certificate.  The private key cannot be obtained from this file, otherwise anybody would be able to extract the key and sign apps under your name.

This is the reason the Android dev guide [heavily recommends you keep your private key safe](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#secure-key).