# I accidentally deleted my android keystore, how do I get it back?

Tags: android, key

Welp, smooth move on my part. I can't update any applications in the Market now because I accidentally deleted my android keystore. Does anyone know how I could get it back? I've tried running a recovery program, but for whatever reason it's not showing up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there way to get private signed keystore file from previous apk release file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184728/is-there-way-to-get-private-signed-keystore-file-from-previous-apk-release-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've lost your private key, it's gone forever (unless you have backups).

Maybe worth trying if you can take your existing APKs, sign them with an *additional* new key and upload them.  Then for subsequent releases, you could use the new key.

Whether this really does work in practice, I'm not so confident, but could be worth a try:
[How to sign an APK with more than one certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881904/how-to-sign-an-apk-with-more-than-one-certificate)

Comment: Let's say I have two people buy my app. If I deleted the application I have in the Market right now, then publish the same app with the new key, will those two people have to buy the app again? It would have the same package name. What do you think?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't delete a Market app, only un-publish? So I would guess that the Market won't let you upload a new version of the same package if the signatures don't match. You'd have to change the package name. You'd need to try it for yourself with a test app.

Comment: @adneal As per my knowledge and sake of your company reputation , you have to pay these too peoples. You can see there all credential from your developer console admin panel .contacts them and pay . then you make a new keystore file and upload and inform these guys too.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably out of luck.

But if it were me, and I knew any bits of the key file at all (such as a header or key name or whatever), I'd immediately unmount that partition and grep the device file for those bits (if you are on windows, boot with a live linux CD).

It probably won't work, but at worst you loose an hour or two of CPU time on a wild goose chase.

Answer (score 0):

Google now allows you to upload the new key to existing app by requesting them to reset it through email/live chat in Google Support.

This process takes 1-2 business days.

I followed this process and uploaded an update to the same app with a new key. 
Google Play Store technical team helped me to reset the previous key.