# signed apk with diff key, error in uploading to playstore

Tags: android, meteor, key, release, android-keystore

I uploaded an apk on google play store last week. Now I deleted my **releasekey.jks** file and created a new one for the updated apk. Google won't let me push through with a different key but they sent me the previous key i used to sign the apk. Is there a way I can use the old sign (sent by google) to sign the apk and replace the new sign in **releasekey.jks** by the old one.

I know google mentions you need to sign the apk with the same key but the deed has been done.
Already gone through [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781721/i-accidentally-deleted-my-android-keystore-how-do-i-get-it-back) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881904/how-to-sign-an-apk-with-more-than-one-certificate)

PS : app made on meteor

Comment: Well, if they sent you the previous key, just replace the old one in your directory where you store it and change the gradle then hit build signed APK in the Studio

Comment: the thing is I can not edit my releasekey.jks file. I am using kse (keystore explorer) to open and read the contents of the file. But I am not able to edit it

Comment: You can edit the name of the jks file which PlayStore has given you, according to your need.

Comment: ahh google playStore just sent me my previous key on mail. they didn't give me any file or so

Answer (score 1):

So I changed the id of my app and then recreated the apk. unPublished my previous app and published the new apk now giving google the responsibility to handle the sign-key for all future updates