# How to extract the apk file using the jarsigner to get the key?

Tags: android, keystore, jarsigner

How to extract the apk file using the jarsigner to get the keystore to update my Android application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184728/is-there-way-to-get-private-signed-keystore-file-from-previous-apk-release-file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not mathematically possible. The complete and entire point behind digital signatures is that they cannot be reverse-engineered except with more computing power than anyone will have.

You should already have the keystore for your app -- you used it once already to sign the APK file. If you lost that keystore file, restore it from a backup.

Comment: How can i backup ? Actually keystore deleted with my old harddisk . how can i get keystore? @CommonsWare